# PDO MYSQL update not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having problems getting an sql query correct to update user profiles. I use (basically) the same query to INSERT the data and it works fine (just without the WHERE id=clientid and without clientid in the execute array. The query below does not update any data in the database.

I tested and made sure that all the variables are being posted and they are. As a sidenote, is this query safe from sql injection?

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_DATABASE",$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);

// Deal with the POST variables here...(excluded)

$sql = "UPDATE clients (firstname, lastname, origincountry, dob, gender, email, phone, address, postal, city, province, referred, notes)
        VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :origincountry, :dob, :gender, :email, :phone, :address, :postal, :city, :province, :referred, :notes)
        WHERE id = :clientid" ;

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname,
                  ':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':origincountry'=>$origincountry,
                  ':dob'=>$dob,
                  ':gender'=>$gender,
                  ':email'=>$email,
                  ':phone'=>$phone,
                  ':address'=>$address,
                  ':postal'=>$postal,
                  ':city'=>$city,
                  ':province'=>$province,
                  ':referred'=>$referred,
                  ':notes'=>$notes,
                  ':clientid'=>$clientid));
```

Comment: Does this output any errors? Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I added that and it still does not show any errors

Comment: Does it work with `beginTransaction` and `commit` ?

Comment: thats invalid sql. google how to do an update.

Comment: I think @rambocoder is correct. I thought all I needed to do was change INSERT INTO to UPDATE. But I need to use UPDATE and SET. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL is invalid. See [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html). (thanks to @rambocoder for pointing that out).

Use this SQL:

```sql
UPDATE clients SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname, origincountry = :origincountry, dob = :dob, gender = :gender, email = :email, phone = :phone, address = :address, postal = :postal, city = :city, province = :province, referred = :referred, notes = :notes
WHERE id = :clientid
```

Comment: Your quick. I was just typing out the new query when I saw it was already done here! Thanks!

Comment: I used a regular expression, that's why :-) Very quick-and-dirty, though. Still had to edit a bit. **Find:** `(.*?),`, **Replace:** `$1 = :$1,`.

Comment: -> Thanks for mentioning regular expressions here. Had never used them before. Took a couple hours to learn about regex but now I am flying through code in notepad++ with this new tool :)

Comment: @mcflause I use Notepad++ too. The thing in it that I use most is NppFTP.